# How to write the following in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I write the following in MVC?

```
        <input type="text" name="ProjectList[' + count++ + '].ID"  value = ' + value + ' />
```

Comment: Assuming you mean ASP.NET MVC here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code expressions in `<%= ... %>` block in the attributes.

```
 <input type="text" name="<%= ProjectList[count++].ID %>"  value = ' + value + ' />
```

If the `value` is meant to be another property of the `ProjectList` item... then setting a local variable would be easier:

```
 <% var item = ProjectList[count++].ID; %>
 <input type="text" name="<%= item.ID %>"  value = '<%= item.value %>' />
```

Albeit that the HTML helpers (see other answer) provides a better approach.

NB. In .NET 4 prefer `<%: ... %>` to ensure things are HTML Encoded.

Comment: I like this more, the *helpers* are not always *helping*...
You should encode it too in .NET 3.5  <%=Html.Encode(item.value)%> and <%=Html.Encode(item.ID)%>

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ProjectList[" + (count++) + "].ID", 
    value, new { @class = "css" }) %>
```